# Map the first five observations of the Iris dataset from numbers to strings

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, scikit-learn

As an introduction to machine learning I have to find the first five names corresponding to the flowers of the Iris dataset from the scikit-learn library.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this, as I'm completely new in the field. I was told I can do some numpy indexing to retrieve these.

I know that the integers in `iris.target` correspond to `0 = 'setosa'`, `1 = 'versicolor'`, `2 = 'virginica'`.

EDIT:
To clarify, what I actually want to achieve is to map the integers to names for the first 5 flowers from `iris.data` (assign setosa, veriscolor or virginica to each of the first five observations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to convert the numbers to their corresponding categories? If so, try:

```py
# Load first five flowers and store them in `y`
y = load_iris()['target'][:5]

# Declare dictionary to map each number to its corresponding text
dictionary = {0:'setosa',1:'versicolor',2:'virginica'}

# Translate each number to text using the dictionary
[dictionary[i] for i in y]
```

You can do the same with `numpy.where`:

```py
# Import numpy
import numpy as np

# Case-like structure
np.where(y == 0, 'setosa',
         np.where(y == 1, 'versicolor',
                  'virginica'))
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, when you load up the `Iris.data` you get 150 entries, I want to know what the names of the first 5 are

Comment: I declared `y` as the first five flowers. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

use pandas if you can. its simple,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"
new_names = ['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width','iris_class']

dataset = pd.read_csv(url, names=new_names, skiprows=0, delimiter=',') # load iris dataset from url

dataset.info() # gives details about your dataset

dataset.head() # this will give you first 5 entries in your dataset

# for more details
# check out this link
# https://medium.com/@yosik81/machine-learning-in-30-minutes-with-python-and-google-colab-6e6dfb77f5e1
```